# Initialize URQL for Svelte the async way (I need to split schema.json in a separate chunk)

Tags: svelte, rollup, code-splitting, svelte-3, urql

I'm using Svelte and URQL.

I'm using the [svelte example in your packages folder here](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/blob/main/packages/svelte-urql/example/src/App.svelte) except I'm creating a `format: 'esm'` in my `rollup.config.js`.

My Rollup is already code-splitting my final bundle in chunks when I use `import('./Component.svelte')` in my code.

What I'm having hard time doing is initializing urql asynchronously, like this:

```js
import { initClient, dedupExchange, fetchExchange } from '@urql/svelte'
import { cacheExchange } from "@urql/exchange-graphcache";

const exchanges = [
  cacheExchange({
    resolvers: { /*... my resolvers*/ },
    schema // I need this async, something like: await import('./schema').then(result => result.default)
  }),
  fetchExchange
]

export function initURQL () {
  initClient({
    url: 'http://localhost/graphql',
    exchanges
  })
}
```

If I use something like:

```js
export async function initURQL () {
  const schema = await import('./schema.json').default

  const exchanges = [
  cacheExchange({
    resolvers: {},
    schema
  }),
  fetchExchange
  ]
  initClient({
    url: 'http://localhost/graphql',
    exchanges
  })
}`
```

and call it from `App.svelte` with `;(async () => await initURQL())()` it gives me error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Function called outside component initialization
```

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using URQL but I've run into this error as well.

Unfortunately, you can't call `getContext` or `setContext` (which is what `initClient` in `urql/packages/svelte-urql/src/context.ts` calls) asynchronously.

https://svelte.dev/docs#setContext:

> Like lifecycle functions, this must be called during component initialisation.

https://github.com/timhall/svelte-apollo/issues/9#issuecomment-646184888 answers a very similar question and hopefully points to a suitable workaround for you:

> this happens with getClient and setClient because it is a svelte
> context which is only available at component initialization
> (construction) and cannot be in an event handler. see: the answer for
> [Svelte user registration issue with setting store value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60591927/svelte-user-registration-issue-with-setting-store-value)
> Most likely what is happening is that you're calling it in an async
> event su as an on:click, onMount, onDestroy when it is not available.
> The solution to this is to store your client as a store in the context
> as per
> https://svelte.dev/tutorial/context-api.
>
> In general it should probably look something like:
>
> ```
> setClient(writable(apolloClient));
>
> let client
> getClient().subscribe((_client) => client = _client);
> ```